# Redmine filter or report to see historical data

Tags: reporting, filtering, redmine, usage-statistics

I'm trying to find usage statistics for the "statuses" in our Redmine data. I'm using two filters: The tracker and the status. I realized that these filters only show tasks which are currently in that particular status. To find out the total usage statistics I need to find out the historical data, too, which means if a task was marked with a particular status in the past, it should be counted.

There isn't any current filter or report in Redmine which can give me those numbers. Do you know of any other methods to query historical data in Redmine?

(We're changing our tracker, status and workflows and we want to remove those unused statuses from the workflows. To make that decision, we need to find out which statuses were useful and functional in the past.)